# Finding Highest occurrence in file

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

Passing an Integer arrayList. I get how to find the max and add that to a separate arrayList. But how would I be able to continue find the max. Not trying to use a selection sort algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are right. You can use a hashmap. Try this code ->

```java
public static Hashmap<String, Integer> letterInstances(String file)throws IOException{
    Hashmap<String, String> instanceMap = Hashmap<String, String>;
  

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));//scanner accesses file
    
    
    while(reader.hasNext()){
       String line = reader.nextLine();
       for(int i = 0; i< line.length(); i++){
           String character = line.get(i).toString().toLowerCase();
           int count = 0;
           if(instanceMap.containsKey(character)) count = instanceList.get(character);
           instanceMap.put(character, count)
       }
      
       return instanceMap;

}
```

Or if you also want to sort them to get the first 5 results, use this ->

```java
public List<Entry<String, Integer>> getTop5(Hashmap map){

    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();

    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(
            set);

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                Entry<String, Integer> o2) {

            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }

    });
    System.out.println(list.subList(0, 5)); // this is the list of largest 5 characters in count
    return list.subList(0, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can not use a `HashMap`, you can try this.

Comments in the code.

**Code**

```
mport java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick(sedj601)
 */
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Fake file data
        String dataToRead = 
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
        printing and typesetting industry Lorem 
        Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy 
        text ever since thes when an unknown printer 
        took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a 
        type specimen book It has survived not only five 
        centuries but also the leap into electronic typesetting 
        remaining essentially unchanged It was popularised in the 
        a with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
        Lorem Ipsum passages and more recently with desktop 
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including 
        versions of Lorem Ipsum";        
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList(dataToRead.toUpperCase().split("\n"));//Capatilize the data as you read it.
        
        List<String> keyCapitalLetters = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ".split("")));//Use this List like you would use the key part of a HashMap.
        //data.forEach(System.out::println);
        List<Integer> valuescounters = new ArrayList();//Use this list like you would use the value part of a HashMap
        //Set all the counters values to zero.
        for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            valuescounters.add(0);
        }
        
        //Process the fake data line by line
        for(String line : data)
        {
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
            for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)//Read each character of each line.
            {                
                int index = keyCapitalLetters.indexOf(String.valueOf(line.charAt(i)));//find the index in the key List of the characters that is being read.
                valuescounters.set(index, valuescounters.get(index) + 1);//Increment the counter value in the value list.
                System.out.println("Char: " + line.charAt(i) + "\tIndex: " + index);
            }
        }
        
        //Remove the space character.
        keyCapitalLetters.remove(" ");
        valuescounters.remove(26);
        
        //Print the output of the key and value list.
        System.out.println("\nCount:");
        for(int i = 0; i < keyCapitalLetters.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(keyCapitalLetters.get(i) + ": " + valuescounters.get(i));
        }
        
        doSelectionSort(keyCapitalLetters, valuescounters);//Sort.
        //Print After sort.
        System.out.println("\nSorted:");     
        for(int i = 0; i < keyCapitalLetters.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(keyCapitalLetters.get(i) + ": " + valuescounters.get(i));
        }
        
        //Print Five Highest.
        System.out.println("\nHighest Five");
        List<String> keysFiveHighest = keyCapitalLetters.subList(keyCapitalLetters.size() - 5, keyCapitalLetters.size());
        List<Integer> valuesFiveHighest = valuescounters.subList(valuescounters.size() - 5, valuescounters.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < keysFiveHighest.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(keysFiveHighest.get(i) + ": " + valuesFiveHighest.get(i));
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nHighest - " + keyCapitalLetters.get(keyCapitalLetters.size() - 1) + ": " + valuescounters.get(valuescounters.size() -1 ));
        System.out.println("\nLowest - " + keyCapitalLetters.get(0) + ": " + valuescounters.get(0));
        
        
        
        
    }    
    
    public static void doSelectionSort(List<String> keyList, List<Integer> valuesList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < valuesList.size(); i++) {
            // find position of smallest num between (i + 1)th element and last element
            int pos = i;
            for (int j = i; j < valuesList.size(); j++) {
                if (valuesList.get(j) < valuesList.get(pos))
                    pos = j;
            }
            // Swap min (smallest num) to current position on array
            int minValue = valuesList.get(pos);
            String minKey = keyList.get(pos);
            
            valuesList.set(pos, valuesList.get(i));
            keyList.set(pos, keyList.get(i));
            
            valuesList.set(i, minValue);
            keyList.set(i, minKey);            
        }
    }    
}
```

**OutPut**

```
Sorted:
J: 0
Q: 0
Z: 0
X: 2
B: 5
V: 5
F: 6
W: 6
K: 7
C: 10
G: 11
Y: 13
H: 14
D: 16
U: 17
P: 19
M: 19
L: 22
R: 24
O: 25
A: 30
I: 38
N: 38
S: 38
T: 43
E: 59

Highest Five
I: 38
N: 38
S: 38
T: 43
E: 59

Highest - E: 59

Lowest - J: 0
```

Comment: OP also wants to sort and get the largest 5 values.

Comment: I missed that while reading the OP's question.

Comment: That's no issue. You can edit it

Comment: @Sambhav.K, I still did not see top 5. I see highest and lowest.

Comment: Pls check his code in the end. He is logging Top 5 Letters

Comment: I updated the code to show the five highest values and the highest and lowest values.

Comment: Actually I don't get it why u r using a list. Why not hashmap? That's better and convenient way. Needs less code and keeps the code optimised.

Comment: My understanding is the OP did not want to use `HashMap`. I say that at the top of this answer.

Comment: Hmmmm. I missed that out. Tnx

Comment: Is it then not possible to take the integer value from the list and add find if its a largest or smallest value. But by doing so would is it still possible to keep which char it was assigned to initially? This is from the code I originally had

Comment: I don't understand your question. This example finds the five highest values, the top value, and the smallest value. It shows the character and how many times it appears in the text.